# Classify groups of order 100

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, group-isomorphism

So I am currently trying to Classify all groups of order 100 through an extensive proof; and this is as far as I have gotten so far, wondering how to go beyond the fact that both squares (Z4 & Z25) are isomorphic to the group, any help would be great.

Classify all groups of order 100.

G=|100|

P=C25P=C25, Q=C4Q=C4, |im(ϕ)|=1|im(ϕ)|=1: 11 group;

P=C25P=C25 , Q=C4Q=C4 , |im(ϕ)|=2|im(ϕ)|=2 : 11 group;

P=C25P=C25 , Q=C4Q=C4 , |im(ϕ)|=4|im(ϕ)|=4 : 11 group;

P=C25P=C25 , Q=C22Q=C22 , |im(ϕ)|=1|im(ϕ)|=1 : 11 group;

P=C25P=C25 , Q=C22Q=C22 , |im(ϕ)|=2|im(ϕ)|=2 : 11 group;

P=C25P=C25 , Q=C22Q=C22 , |im(ϕ)|=4|im(ϕ)|=4 : not possible;

P=C25P=C52 , Q=C4Q=C4 , |im(ϕ)|=1|im(ϕ)|=1 : 11 group;

P=C25P=C52 , Q=C4Q=C4 , |im(ϕ)|=2|im(ϕ)|=2 : 22 groups;

P=C25P=C52 , Q=C4Q=C4 , |im(ϕ)|=4|im(ϕ)|=4 : 44 groups;

P=C25P=C52 , Q=C22Q=C22 , |im(ϕ)|=1|im(ϕ)|=1 : 11 group;

P=C25P=C52 , Q=C22Q=C22 , |im(ϕ)|=2|im(ϕ)|=2 : 22 groups;

P=C25P=C52 , Q=C22Q=C22 , |im(ϕ)|=4|im(ϕ)|=4 : 11 group.

These numbers are prime, lagrange implies prime groups are cyclic therefore cyclic groups, only one group of each order (up to isomorphism).

Z4

If G has an element of order 4, it is cyclic, assume no element of order 4 G={e,a,b,c}

order a = order b = order c = 2

claim ab = c

if ab = e, then a = b^-1, contradicts b = b^-1

ab = a implies b = e

while ab = b implies a = e

same argument shows ba = c = ab, ca = b = ac, cb = a = bc

G: Z2 x Z2 is isomorphic to G

f(e) = (0,0) f(a) = (1,0), f(b) = (0,1), f(c) = (1,1)

Tips on moving forward?

Comment: This is very disorganized and difficult to read, so it's hard to tell what progress you've made.  You seem to be writing down random facts without indicating how they're connected to each other and the overall proof. For example, you say that "G is a semidirect product of N with H" and then suddenly list the abelian groups of order 100.

Comment: Order 64 is the really hard order, most others are trivial.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ is NOT isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: Also you seem to keep changing the meaning of $G$. You should stick to $G$ being a group of order $100$ and use different symbols for the Sylow 2- and Sylow 5-subgroups. You cannot assume that there are no elements of order 4 or 25.

Comment: @Schipperus But fortunately for him he is only doing 100, not all groups order $\le100$ :)

Comment: There are $16$ groups of order $100$. Without electronic help, it is probably difficult to find them.

Answer (score 3):

If $|G|=100$ then $G = P \rtimes_\phi Q$ with $P\in{\rm Syl}_5(G)$ and $Q \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)$. Here is a summary of the number of isomorphism classes of groups in the various situations. Most of these are not hard to prove.

$P=C_{25}$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=1$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{25}$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=2$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{25}$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=4$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{25}$, $Q=C_2^2$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=1$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{25}$, $Q=C_2^2$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=2$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{25}$, $Q=C_2^2$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=4$: not possible;

$P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=1$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=2$: $2$ groups;

$P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=4$: $4$ groups;

$P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_2^2$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=1$: $1$ group;

$P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_2^2$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=2$: $2$ groups;

$P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_2^2$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=4$: $1$ group.

The hardest case is probably $P=C_{5}^2$, $Q=C_4$, $|{\rm im}(\phi)|=4$. There is one group in which ${\rm im}(\phi)$ acts trivially on one direct factor of $P$, one in which it acts as a group of order $4$ on one factor and $2$ on the other factor, and two groups in which it acts as groups of order $4$ on both factors.

It might help to think of ${\rm im}(\phi)$ as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,5)$.